# Dropdown menu text ignores lines, doesn't inherit font-size

Tags: html, css

I am building a simple nav bar, nesting `<ul>` lists inside a `div`.

following [this tutorial](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-simple-css-dropdown-menu), I tried implementing a simple css dropdown menu into my navbar.

I am using `reset.css` and a custom icons font called `ionicons`, but I've built the snipped without them and recreated the problem.

For some reason, the dropdown that shows on hover has bigger text, and the text is bigger than the font-line (it overlaps). I thought the dropdown would just inherit font-style from the parent element, but apparently that's not the case.

I tried setting it manually, but so far haven't been able to change it.

I'm out of idea on what to try and what I'm doing wrong. Snippet below

```css
html {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  html {
    margin: 0 5%;
  }
}
/********************************
NAVBAR
********************************/

#navbar {
  background-color: #913D88;
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  #navbar {
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
}
#navbar ul {
  list-style: none;
}
#navbar ul li {
  padding: 0.5em;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: 400;
  display: inline-block;
}
@media (min-width: 767px) {
  #navbar ul li {
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }
}
#navbar ul li a {
  padding: 0.3em;
  background-color: #913D88;
}
#navbar ul li a:visited,
#navbar ul li a:link {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#navbar ul li a:hover {
  color: #491f45;
  background-color: #c371ba;
}
#navbar ul .dropdown {
  position: relative;
}
#navbar ul .dropdown:hover > .drop-nav {
  display: block;
}
#navbar ul .dropdown .drop-nav {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
#navbar ul .dropdown .drop-nav li {
  padding: 0.5em;
  display: block;
  background-color: #913D88;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
#navbar ul .dropdown .drop-nav a {
  padding: 0.3em;
  background-color: #913D88;
}
#navbar ul .dropdown .drop-nav a:visited,
#navbar ul .dropdown .drop-nav alink {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#navbar ul .dropdown .drop-nav a:hover {
  color: #491f45;
  background-color: #c371ba;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>ZIC Knjižnica</title>

  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,900&amp;subset=latin-ext,latin' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://www.ijs.si/ijsw">IJS</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">knjižnica</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">zaloga&nbsp;<span class="ion-arrow-down-b"></a>
        <ul class="drop-nav">
          <li><a href="#">novi izvodi tiskanih revij</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">elektronske revije</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">katalog</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">baze podatkov</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">storitve&nbsp;<span class="ion-arrow-down-b"></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">ENG</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can read in the following resource, the `em` unit is a relative value to the parent's value.
So if you have a parent element with a `font-size:1.1em` and its child has also `font-size:1.1em` then the children's font-size would actually be `1.1*1.1*{Top parent font-size}` and therefore, those links look bigger.

**Solution 1:**
If for instance I'll change the `#navbar ul li` to a `px` size, the font-size of both the main links and the on-hover links would be the same.

```
#navbar ul li{
 font-size: 14px;
}
```

**Solution 2:**
Set `1em` as a font-size to the links in the dropdown.

```
#navbar ul .dropdown .drop-nav a{
 font-size: 1em;
}
```

Regarding the line-height glitch, after few checks it seems that the glitch is being caused due to the padding. Consider resetting the padding of the `dropdown li a` element, as follows:

```
#navbar ul .dropdown .drop-nav a{
 padding: 0;
}
```

**[Resource: Chapter 4: The amazing em unit](http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/css2em.htm)**

> When used to specify font sizes, the em unit refers to the font size
>   of the parent element. So, in the example above, the font size of the
>   h1 element is set to be two times the font size of the body element.
>   In order to find what the font size of the h1 element will be, we need
>   to know the font size of body . Since this isn't specified in the the
>   style sheet, the browser will have to find it from somewhere else - a
>   good place to look is in the user's preferences. So, if the user has
>   set the normal font size to be 10 points, the size of the h1 element
>   will be 20 points. This will make document headlines stand out
>   relative to the the surrounding text. Therefore: always use ems to set
>   font sizes.

Comment: changed the link font-size to 1em and now it's fine. This still doesn't change the line-height problem though

Comment: Line-height? Will check it

Comment: as in, I changed the child-element font-size to 1em, and now it inherits the parent's font-size, which is what I wanted in the first place

Comment: you can see it in the snippet, for some reason the padding, and the text overlap the previous line (when it breaks the link text into two lines). I tried just setting the line-height to 1em, but nothing changed.

Comment: Consider setting the line-height to `1.3em` maybe

Comment: A better solution: `#navbar ul .dropdown .drop-nav a{ padding: 0; }`

Comment: set the line-height to 1.3em, then had to reset the top to 95%, as it was overlapping the main nav-bar. Got it set up the way I want it, but this has kind of a dirty workaround feel. Thanks for the help anyway

Comment: If you'd reset the padding as mentioned in the comment above, you **won't** have to edit the `top` or the `line-height`.

Comment: yeah, but then I won't have any padding on my anchors, which makes them hard to read, and weird looking

Comment: This specific padding-reset is regarding the dropdown anchors only. I modified it and it looked good. Combine it with a "below-1" font-size like: `font-size: 0.8em` and you might find a good visual combination you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the size manually by adding font-size property in css.

```
#navbar ul .dropdown .drop-nav a {
 padding: 0.3em;
  background-color: #913D88;
  font-size:10px;
 }
```

You can change the font size to what you require.

Answer (score 0):

```
#navbar ul .dropdown .drop-nav a {
padding: 0.3em;
background-color: #913D88;
font-size: 20px;
}
```

You can choose the font size as per your need. You can use 2nd method also.

The problem arised bcoz you didnot give the font size to the parent tag
if you will give font size to the parent, then the child will already inherit it.

```
#navbar ul li a {
padding: 0.3em;
background-color: #913D88;
font-size: 10px;
}
```